# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in C:\wamp\www\xyz\contact-form.php on line 4

Tags: php, forms

I'm getting the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in C:\wamp\www\xyz\contact-form.php on line 4

On a contact form that I'm trying to create for my portfolio site. I'm creating a simple check for the form submission and if it doesn't exist, it'll re-direct you back to to the index.

My code is:

```
if (!isset($_POST["save"]) || $_POST["save"] != ”contact”) {
        header(“Location: index.php”);
        exit;
}
```

Line 4 is the `header()` call, and I can't see what I've done wrong. I expect it's a small syntax error, any ideas?

Comment: Those curly/smart quotes are beautiful, yet "deadly". You either took that code from a website somewhere, or you're using Microsoft Word or Windows WordPad as your editor.

Comment: An IDE would've helped you out here... syntax highlighting + default encoding for the win :)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I'm using Sublime Text 2 at the moment. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @ElliotBlackburn: There's a lot of them out there... it all depends on what you've got to do (I like vim for C, PHPStorm for PHP + vim for git conflicts... drRacket for scheme, Visual Studio for C++ and XCode for Objective-C...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quotes aren't right, I'm assuming you copied it from a site, should be `"` not `“`

Comment: Took me ages staring at that, I copied it from something I did for an assignment and for some reason it did that. Oh well, sorted it now! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You're using funny quotes: (also known as smart quotes and curly quotes)

```
if (!isset($_POST["save"]) || $_POST["save"] != ”contact”) {
    header(“Location: index.php”);
```

should be:

```
if (!isset($_POST["save"]) || $_POST["save"] != "contact") {
    header("Location: index.php");
```

Comment: As for these as well `header(“Location: index.php”);` to `header("Location: index.php");`

Comment: Indeed. Kinda weird my eyes didn't pick those up. Must need more caffeine. :)

Comment: I'm on my second cup now ;-)